# Talend - Issue when using Dynamic Schema with CSV file

Tags: file, csv, dynamic, etl, talend

I'm reading a csv file Dynamically but it seems that this data structure is deleting the first row (The mot important one in my case)

[image]

[image]

You can see that my file contains 109 row but the tFileInput seems to read 108.

Same file, with same configuration and changing Dynamic to String is working perfectly.

[image]

I need to read the file dynamically because columns number is variable and is I need to pivot my file according to the first missing line.

Any Idea ? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

ok. This is a know thing when you are using dynamic schema. i took this snip from talend documentation for you to read,

```
HEADER:Enter the number of rows to be skipped in the beginning of file.

Note that when dynamic schema is used, the first row of the input data is always treated as the header row no matter whether the Header field value is set or not. For more information about dynamic schema, see Talend Studio User Guide.
```